# "Instancing" Geometry and attach to models?

Tags: mesh

I am building a character model for a game engine.
At the moment, I am duplicating the objects the character can hold:
[image]
"pistols" in this case are identical, just with different bone weights.
I would like to have exactly one "original" pistol and carrying/holding it in different places is just a copy of it with different bone weights and exporting the model to fbx or gltf then yields a object hierarchy how it is now with duplicated but identical meshes.
(my engine does not allow attaching meshes to objects, which is why I keep them inside the model)

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Within Blender, you would do this by using a single pistol mesh data block shared across multiple pistol objects, but how to do it for exporting depends on the game engine.

Comment: @TheLabCat how do I separate the bone weights?
They are part of the pistol mesh data when I use the data block approach

Comment: Oh. Um, yeah, there's no way out of that, unless you maybe have low-poly versions of the gun with the desired bone weights to copy to it via modifiers..? But, this sounds like a problem you're trying to solve the wrong way because of a fundamental misunderstanding of how this game engine works.

Comment: Or rather Blender does not have such functionality in the first place